# Cut audiofile into several pieces (java)

Tags: java, audio

I need to play a large audio file and while playing mark beginning and and of many places in that file (one audio record contains many question-answer pairs, so I am parsing these pairs manually while listening). Then I need to get a separate audio file which contains only part of original audio file (between I pressed startClip and endClip). So one audiofile will be marked in this way and cut into multiple files (maybe some of its parts will be left out and won't be part of any resulting files).

File format is any, I can convert my original WMA to anything (JavaFX 8 has no support for WMA).

I cannot find any ways how to do it.  Seems standard API doesn't help:
JavaFX sound api:  [Package javafx.scene.media][1]

I also learned about some sound frameworks, but can't tell they help:

[JSyn](https://github.com/philburk/jsyn)

[Beads](http://www.beadsproject.net)

Java OpenAL (JOAL) - for games/3D sound

LWJGL - Lightweight Java Game Library (enables native APIs for graphics (OpenGL), audio (OpenAL) and parallel computing (OpenCL)) - for games/3D sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
```

I think this simple code may help you :

```
class Sound {
    protected String path;
    protected AudioFormat format;
    protected AudioInputStream sound2;
    protected SourceDataLine ausgabe;
    protected File soundfile;
    protected DataLine.Info data;
    protected byte buffer[]=new byte[1000000];
    protected boolean isplaying=false;
    protected boolean stop=false;
    protected int speed=5;
    protected int count=0;

    public Sound(String path2) {
        try {
        path=path2;
        soundfile=new File(path);
        sound2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundfile);
        format=sound2.getFormat();
        data=new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class,format);
        ausgabe=(SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(data);
        buffer=new byte[1000000];
        } catch (Exception bug) {
            System.out.println(bug);
        }
    }
    public void reload(String path2) {
        try {
        path=path2;
        soundfile=new File(path);
        sound2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundfile);
        format=sound2.getFormat();
        data=new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class,format);
        ausgabe=(SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(data);
        buffer=new byte[1000000];
        } catch (Exception bug) {
            System.out.println(bug);
        }
    }
    public void setspeed(int speedn) {
        speed=speedn;
    }
    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return isplaying;
    }
    public void stop() {
        stop=true;
    }
    public void play() {
        try {
        ausgabe.open(format);
        ausgabe.start();
        isplaying=true;
        stop=false;
        count=0;
        while ((count=sound2.read(buffer,0,buffer.length)) != -1) {
            if (stop==true) {
                break;
            }
            /*try {
            Thread.sleep(speed);
            } catch(InterruptedException bug) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            System.out.println(bug);
            }*/
            if (count > 0) {
                ausgabe.write(buffer, 0, count);
            } 
        }
        count=0;
        ausgabe.drain();
        ausgabe.close();
        isplaying=false;
        } catch (LineUnavailableException bug) {
            System.out.println(bug);
        } catch (IOException bug) {
            System.out.println(bug);
        }
    }
}

class Recorder {
    protected String type;
    protected AudioFileFormat.Type soundtype;
    protected AudioFormat format;
    protected TargetDataLine eingabe;
    protected File writefile;
    protected DataLine.Info data;
    protected boolean isrecording=false;
    protected boolean stop=false;

    public Recorder(String pathn,String typen) {
        try {
        writefile=new File(pathn);
        format=new AudioFormat(44100.0F,16,1,true,false);
        data=new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class,format);
        if (typen=="AIFC") {
            soundtype = AudioFileFormat.Type.AIFC;
        }
        if (typen=="AIFF") {
            soundtype = AudioFileFormat.Type.AIFF;
        }
        if (typen=="WAVE") {
            soundtype = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;
        }
        if (typen=="AU") {
            soundtype = AudioFileFormat.Type.AU;
        }
        if (typen=="SND") {
            soundtype = AudioFileFormat.Type.SND;
        }
        eingabe=(TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(data);
        } catch (Exception bug) {
            System.out.println(bug);
        }
    }
    public void format(float rate, int bits,int channels, boolean signed, boolean endian) {
        format=new AudioFormat(rate,bits,channels,signed,endian);
    }
    public void settype(String typen) {
        if (typen=="AIFC") {
            soundtype = AudioFileFormat.Type.AIFC;
        }
        if (typen=="AIFF") {
            soundtype = AudioFileFormat.Type.AIFF;
        }
        if (typen=="WAVE") {
            soundtype = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;
        }
        if (typen=="AU") {
            soundtype = AudioFileFormat.Type.AU;
        }
        if (typen=="SND") {
            soundtype = AudioFileFormat.Type.SND;
        }
    }
    public void setname(String pathn) {
        writefile = new File(pathn);
    }
    public boolean isRecording() {
        return isrecording;
    }
    public void stop() {
        try {
        isrecording=false;
        eingabe.stop();
        eingabe.close();
        } catch (Exception bug){
            System.out.println(bug);
        }
    }
    public void record() {
        try {
            isrecording=true;
            eingabe.open(format);
            eingabe.start();
            AudioSystem.write(new AudioInputStream(eingabe),soundtype,writefile);
        } catch (Exception bug){
            System.out.println(bug);
        }
    }
}

class Arrayhelper {
    public Arrayhelper() {
    }
    public int[][] append(int[][] array,int[] element) {
         int[][] rarray = new int[array.length+1][];
         for (int iter7=0;iter7 < array.length;iter7=iter7+1) {
             rarray[iter7]=array[iter7];     
         }
         rarray[array.length]=element;
         return rarray;
    }
    public int[][] remove(int[][] array,int iterator) {
         try {
         int[][] rarray = new int[array.length-1][];

         int rarray_iter=-1;
         for (int iter8=0;iter8 < array.length;iter8=iter8+1) {
             rarray_iter=rarray_iter+1;
             if (iter8==iterator) {
                 rarray_iter=rarray_iter-1;
             }
             else {
                 rarray[rarray_iter]=array[iter8];
             }     
         }
         rarray_iter=0;
         return rarray;
         }
         catch (java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException bug) {
         System.out.println(bug);
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
         return array;
         }
    }
}
```

**Note :** 
This the reads "the volume", a audio file are changing volumes.

```
count=sound2.read(buffer,0,buffer.length)
```

For example if you want to go over one "tone", just call it twice.
So you could provide cutting, make a large byte[], read the whole sound file into it, cut the array using System.arraycopy, and use the write function to write it all down.